# Is it possible to take another Pale Blue Dot image?

Tags: new-horizons, earth

> Pale Blue Dot is a photograph of planet Earth taken on February 14,
>   1990, by the Voyager 1 space probe from a record distance of about 6
>   billion kilometers (3.7 billion miles, 40.5 AU), as part of that day's
>   Family Portrait series of images of the Solar System.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pale_Blue_Dot).

Would it be possible to take another Pale Blue Dot image using New Horizons? Will the apparent size of Earth be again smaller than a pixel? February 14, 2020 would be pleasant date.

Of course all images taken of Kuiper belt objects should be transmitted to Earth before.

Comment: A quick search of the PDS shows they haven't done this (no NH images with target = Earth show up).

Answer (score 2):

Plenty of probes have taken [photos of earth from deep space](http://www.planetary.org/explore/space-topics/earth/pics-of-earth-by-planetary-spacecraft.html) since Voyager.

The one [from Saturn's orbit](http://www.planetary.org/multimedia/space-images/earth/earth-and-moon-from-saturn.html) (Cassini Spacecraft) and the one taken by the [Juno probe shortly after launch](http://www.planetary.org/multimedia/space-images/earth/20131230_juno20110830-full.html) stand out as quite similar to the original pale blue dot pictures.

This one (also from Cassini) is visually quite stunning:

http://www.planetary.org/multimedia/space-images/earth/the-day-the-earth-smiled.html

I am not aware of any pictures like this from New Horizons, though.

Comment: The first image in the link 'from Jupiter's orbit" was not taken from Jupiter's orbit. The caption indicates it was taken 3 weeks after launch, so Juno was not even close to Jupiter. 10 million kilometers may not even rank as "deep space" in comparison to other images. :-)

Comment: @JohnHoltz That's true - sloppy of me